# multiple textbox 2 way bind

Tags: c#, textbox

perhaps the title is incorrect but i have no other idea on how to ask.
i have a windows form with multiple tabs that uses a singleton. well my form has roughly 50+ textboxes that stores user input to my singleton properties and then saves to an xml. my question is what would be the less complicated route for reading the xml and displaying on the textboxes what what saved to the xml?
example code:

```
public class ContactInfo
   {
    public string Name { get { return Firstname + " " + LastName; } }

    public string Firstname { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }

    public string Address1 { get; set; }

    public string Address2 { get; set; }

    public string City { get; set; }

    public string State { get; set; }

    public string ZipCode { get; set; }
   }
public class Site
{
Site()
 {
        OfficeAddress = new ContactInfo();
        ShippingAddress = new ContactInfo();
        DirectorOfOperationsFandB = new ContactInfo();
        DirectorOfOperationsRetail = new ContactInfo();
        SecondInCharge = new ContactInfo();
        SiteController = new ContactInfo();
        SiteContact = new ContactInfo();
  }
    public ContactInfo OfficeAddress { get; set; }

    public ContactInfo ShippingAddress { get; set; }

    public ContactInfo DirectorOfOperationsFandB { get; set; }

    public ContactInfo DirectorOfOperationsRetail { get; set; }

    public ContactInfo SecondInCharge { get; set; }
  }
```

i started to do textbox1.text = Site.OfficeAdress.Address1; and so on but you cant imagine how many lines that would take up.

Comment: Is this Winforms or WPF?

Comment: windows form Dan Puzey.

Comment: Then your best bet is probably lots of lines of code...

Comment: i really haven't done much with WPF but if i was to do it in WPF how would you do it then?

Comment: Do it in the designer. Drag a BindingSource (or several) onto the form set the BindingSource.Datasource to your object and go through each text box and set the bindings in the property window. Sure it makes lots of auto-code but its reasonably quick to do.

Comment: In WPF it'd be lots of lines of markup.  An alternative approach would be a list of fieldname-value pairs, where you could bind to the list and use much less markup, but you then lose the benefit of a decent model type.  Really you should just bite the bullet: if you have 50 separate fields, you need to assign 50 separate values (or bindings).

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the textBox two way like this:

```
textBox1.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", ds, "customers.custName"));
```

For futher details
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.databindings.aspx

Comment: Thanks for speedy response but that would still require me to do it for each textbox,no?

Comment: yes ofcourse :). But it will serve the two way binding, therefore will save code to tie back the values to the dataset.